# Цветовая математика в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, цвета

Используя `Less` можно делать операции над цветами, например `darken("red",10%)`.

Есть ли в стандартном JavaScript функции для работы с цветом?

Если нету, то может быть есть легковесные библиотеки для этого, если есть, то какие?

Comment: _есть ли в стандартном JavaScript функции для работы с цветом?_ - нет

Comment: @Grundy а в новых стандартах? я могу babel использовать, если это поможет

Comment: В яваскрипте нет понятия _цвет_. :) Но на самом деле довольно просто по трем составляющим перевести сначала в другую систему, уменьшить яркость, и перевести обратно

Comment: пример реализации можно посмотреть в [том же Less](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/functions/color.js)

Answer (score 2):

В `CSS` есть свои собственные переменные, по сути их можно адаптировать и использовать для этого.

Пример:

```css
:root {
  --opacity: 1;
}

div {
  /*пример*/
  background: hsla( 16, 100%, 50%, calc(var(--opacity) *.9));
  /*другие стили*/
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>Sample Text</div>
```

Comment: Интересно, спасибо за ответ! Не знал про такое применение `calc` Хоть мне ответ и не подходит, так как нужны циклы и вообще возможности JavaScript, но ставлю плюс, так как интересное решение.